# How to correctly create an odometry message

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

I creating a driver for my motors and I'm wondering how to create a "good" odometry data to send on the /odom topic.
For instance, I know [that documentation](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) but I'm wondering if I should initialize all the parameters, especially the header part.

This is the header :

```
uint32 seq
time stamp
string frame_id
```

Should I declare stuff like `header.frame_id="base_link"` or is it automatically done in some way ?

For now my Odometry data is an attribute of my class robot, should I redeclare a new nav_msgs::Odometry each time I'm sending an information on the /odom topic for the header information to be updated ? Especially I didn't find constructor declaration as well.

I didn't find any clear explanation on that on the wiki. I plan on using robot_base_efk afterward.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143361/how-to-correctly-create-an-odometry-message/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For any message with a header, you should set the frame_id and stamp. You can ignore seq; it will be set automatically. Reusing the same object, and updating the relevant fields each time you publish should be fine, as long as it hasn't gone out of scope.

The stamp can be set with a `ros::Time` object like `ros::Time::now()`, and frame_id can be set with a string like you did in your question.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-23**:
How am I suppose to initialize it correctly ? I don't understand that at all...
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:

## * stamp.sec: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch

## * stamp.nsec: nanoseconds since stamp_secs

## time-handling sugar is provided by the client library

time stamp

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-03-23**:
Ah, yeah the message definition doesn't make that clear. I'll update my answer.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-23**:
Thanks a lot !

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-23**:
Check out the wiki on ROS Time to understand better what this is about and how to create appropriate objects: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time